# nth best with group by mysql

Tags: mysql

```
Name    Marks
-------------
John    100
John    80
John    70
John    60
Nancy   95
Nancy   88
Nancy   70
Nancy   40
```

I have the above table. I would like to get the 3rd highest marks of each candidate. My output should be

```
Name   Marks
-------------
John    70
Nancy   70
```

In general I would like to make the query flexible to get nth highest marks per candidate (different data). 
I know in mysql, to get nth highest data I can do `order by desc limit n-1,n` but how do I do it for each group.

Answer (score 2):

another one, without variables, the 3 in having clause represents 3rd highest mark.

```
SELECT   a.name,
         a.mark
FROM     your_table a left join your_table b on 
         a.mark<b.mark and a.name=b.name 
GROUP BY a.name, a.mark 
HAVING   (count(b.mark)+1=3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
select t1.*
from your_table t1
join
(
    select name, 
           @rank := case when @prevName = name then @rank + 1 else 1 end as rank,
           @prevName := name
    from your_table
    cross join (select @rank := 0, @prevName := '') tmp
    group by name
    order by name asc, marks desc
) t2 on t1.name = t2.name
where t2.rank = 3
```